# Android Tess-two: library configuration using cygwin

Tags: android, bash, cygwin, tess-two

i am following this tutorial [here](http://kurup87.blogspot.in/2012/03/android-ocr-tutorial-image-to-text.html) to use Tesseract libs for android. and in step(b) in the link posted, it says: `b.export TESSERACT_PATH=${PWD}/external/tesseract-3.01`

and in `cygwin` i wrote the following:

```
dm@me /cygdrive/e/Data/private/Fr/OCR/libs/tess-two-
master/tess-two-master/tess-two
```

but when i execute it i receive the belwo error:

```
 $ export C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR=${PWD}\external\tesseract-3.01
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

please let me know how to fix it, as i am a beginner to cygwin.

**update**:

i tried  ezrepotein4 answer, and now it gives me "not a valid identifier". please , let me know what is "external\tesseract-3.01", i do not have these files/folders...and what is PWD. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this tutorial author uses few linux commands:

- `cd` which changes directory - it is an equevalent of windows `dir`
- `export` which sets environment variable

Before exporting any variable you should change directory to your project dir, because all `$PWD` strings in further commands will be replaced by your current directory.

This tutorial assumes that you compiled tesseract and leptonica and you keep them in project-dir/tess-two/external directory as tesseract-3.01 and leptonica-1.68. Source code for those libraries are in `tess-two/jni` directory in repository as stated in README.md https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two/blob/master/README.md

Code which you are trying yo execute is incorrect both syntactically and semantically. It is incorrect syntactically because you all spaces are treated as separators between arguments. Semantically you are trying to set variable  `C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR` to value of `${PWD}\external\tesseract-3.01`. Instead you should set `TESSERACT_PATH` variable.

To do this try command `TESSERACT_PATH=${PWD}/external/tesseract-3.01` as stated in tutorial. This means that you are setting variable `TESSERACT_PATH` to folder external/tesseract-3.01 in your current dir.

To further inspect a value of this variable type: echo $TESSERACT_PATH.

Comment: thanks for you answer. now it gives me "not a valid identifier". please , let me know what is "external\tesseract-3.01", i do not have these files/folders...and what is PWD. thanks